# Find the increase, decrease in a column of pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to check whether the elements in the column `"GDP"` increase or decrease in comparison to their previous value to create column `"change"`.

```
Quarter:  GDP:      change
1999q3    1934.5    ------
1999q4    1932.3    decline
2000q1    1930.3    decline
2000q2    1960.7    increase
2000q3    1989.5    increase
2000q4    2021.9    increase
2001q1    1771.8    decline
2001q2    1490.3    decline
2001q3    2035.3    increase
```

I've already tried `diff()` function but not sure how it could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `numpy` concept #1

**set up category array and slice it**

```
cats = np.array(['decline', '------', 'increase'])
df.assign(
    change=cats[np.sign(
        np.append(0, np.diff(df.GDP.values, 1))
    ).astype(np.uint8) + 1])
```

## `numpy` concept #2

**nested `np.where`**

```
diffs = df.GDP.diff()
df.assign(
    change=np.where(
        diffs > 0, 'increase', np.where(
            diffs < 0, 'decline', '------')))
```

---

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
out = np.where(df.GDP.diff() > 0, 'increase', 'decline')
out[0] = '------'
```

Comment: Thanks John, your code can detect the change. But in the first value it should leave plank as there are nothing to compare with. Instead it still assign "decline" in the index 0 of column "change".

Comment: @ngoduyvu: That's why I put the `out[0] = '------'` line.  That manually assigns to the first row.  If you've assigned the result of `where()` to a Pandas Series or DataFrame, you probably need to instead say `out.iloc[0] = '------'` or similar.