# Add a state column when another column is increasing/decreasing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a column in a data frame when another column is increasing/decreasing or stays the same with:
 1 -> increasing, 0 -> same, -1 -> decreasing

So if `df['battery'] = [1,2,3,4,7,9,3,3,3,]` 
I would like state to be `df['state'] = [1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,0]`

Comment: Related: [Find the increase, decrease in a column of pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41886388/7851470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) method to get the difference between consecutive values, and then assign the necessary state values by using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['battery'] = [1,2,3,4,7,9,3,3,3]

diff = df['battery'].diff()
df.loc[diff > 0, 'state'] = 1
df.loc[diff == 0, 'state'] = 0
df.loc[diff < 0, 'state'] = -1

print(df)
#    battery  state
# 0        1    NaN
# 1        2    1.0
# 2        3    1.0
# 3        4    1.0
# 4        7    1.0
# 5        9    1.0
# 6        3   -1.0
# 7        3    0.0
# 8        3    0.0
```

---

Or, alternatively, one could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

diff = df['battery'].diff()
df['state'] = np.select([diff < 0, diff > 0], [-1, 1], 0)
# Be careful, default 0 will replace the first NaN as well.

print(df)
#    battery  state
# 0        1      0
# 1        2      1
# 2        3      1
# 3        4      1
# 4        7      1
# 5        9      1
# 6        3     -1
# 7        3      0
# 8        3      0
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick!

```
a = [1,2,3,4,7,9,3,3,3]
b = []

for x in range(len(a)-1):
  b.append((a[x+1] > a[x]) - (a[x+1] < a[x]))

print(b)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

So here's your dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [[[1,2,3,4,7,9,3,3,3]]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['battery'])
>>> df
                       battery
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 3]
```

And finally use `apply` and a `lambda` function in order to generate the required result:

```
>>> df['state'] = df.apply(lambda row: [1 if t - s > 0 else -1 if t-s < 0 else 0 for s, t in zip(row['battery'], row['battery'][1:])], axis=1)
>>> df
                       battery                      state
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 3]  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0]
```

Alternatively, if you want the exact difference between each element in the list, you can use the following:

```
>>> df['state'] = df.apply(lambda row: [t - s for s, t in zip(row['battery'], row['battery'][1:])], axis=1)
>>> df
                       battery                      state
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3, 3]  [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, -6, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.np.sign`

```
pd.np.sign(df.battery.diff().fillna(1))
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6   -1.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
Name: battery, dtype: float64
```